# Why was Slavi continuously changing his position?

Tags: the-equalizer

- [The Equalizer: Fighting a Russian Gang (DENZEL WASHINGTON FIGHT SCENE | With Captions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfNU6JfDN_c)

I observe from this scene that Slavi changes his position throughout the conversation. I.e., he is saying/doing something on one occasion, and on the next occasion, totally saying/doing something else that negates his previous speech/gesture.

If you watch the video, once he was saying he didn't know the girl, then he asked her name and mentioned her age; once he said McCall insults him, next he said he was fucking with him; Once he gave his hand for a handshake, next, he threatens and makes fun of McCall.  I.e., the character is full of unpredictability.

Why was that?

What did the screenwriter want to achieve by that? Do real-life mafias behave this way?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your problem here ... what specifically are you saying is contradictory?  Yes he says "$9000 for one single piece ..." but the overall message is that this isn't nearly enough money to buy her freedom?

Comment: @iandotkelly, if you watch the video, once he was saying he didn't know the girl, then he asked her name and mentioned her age; once he said McCall insults him, next he said he was fucking with him; Once he gave his hand for a handshake, next, he threatens and makes fun of McCall.  I.e., the character is full of unpredictability.

Comment: Probably because he wasn't sure about the caller, and subsequent changes are based on caution and emotion. Slavi seems hot-headed. This is very common among people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What did the screenwriter want to achieve by that?

Slavi is using techniques to intimidate and take power over the other person. He's the Man, the Power-that-be, what he says goes. And you'd better understand that quickly, of fear the outcome.

Interrogation techniques use different aspects of mind-manipulation (hot-and-cold also known as good cop/bad cop, Reid technique/FBI, spies interrogation...).

> You can break some men by bullying, on others this has the reverse effect. Decide beforehand whether you are likely to obtain results with the subject you are dealing with, either by bullying, by sarcasm, by cold and impassive treatment, or by sympathy and by working on his emotions (Lieutenant Colonel Oreste Pinto, MI5 interrogator)

In this scene, Slavi is doing just that: he shows interest, empathy, sarcasm, then he tries to instil fear by quickly switching to intimidation. He's blowing hot and cold. The big gap between listening and showing empathy then roaring at McCall has a goal: take power by intimidating. I can be as bad an ass as I can seem nice. He rejects all points, and gives his. I'm the Boss, get out now!

That's when McCall decides that Slavi has made his point and there's no more discussion. Action!

Comment: Do real-life mafias behave this way?

Comment: I never had to face a mob so I can't Say :) but many mafia movies depict scary dudes acting like that

Comment: @user366312.... its not really a fair question to ask, ask anything like that of any large group of people, you'll have lots of variability.  Some might, most might not.  Its definitely a stereotype of a certain type of gangster.